# Async method does not return a value and is stuck

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I want to obtain the user data of a logged in user from Google Firebase. 
For this i wrote two methods; one obtains the `authState` and the other one obtains `UserInfo` containing more detailed information.

These are the two methods implemented in a service which is called `UserService`:

```
constructor(private fireStore: AngularFirestore, private fireAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
}

public async getAuthorizedUser(): Promise<UserInfo> {
  console.log('Awaiting Promise');
  const user: firebase.User = await this.fireAuth.authState.toPromise();
  console.log('User', user);
  return this.getUserInfo(user.uid);
}

private async getUserInfo(uid: string): Promise<UserInfo> {
  return this.fireStore.collection('users', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', uid))
             .get()
             .pipe(
               map((item: firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) => new UserInfo(item.docs[0].data(), item.docs[0].id))).toPromise();
}
```

I am calling the `getAuthorizedUser` method from a button event handler implemented in a component. 
The html element of the button looks like this:

```
<button mat-button (click)="test()">test</button>
```

and the `test()` method is implemented as:

```
async test() {
  console.log('Starting Test');
  const testVariable = await this.userService.getAuthorizedUser();
  console.log('Test', testVariable);
}
```

Furthermore, the `userService` is the dependency injected `UserService`.

The console shows:

> Starting Test 
>   Awaiting Promise

It therefore seems to me that the async call is not returning at all because i would expect to see a logging

> Test

or

> User {...}

or both.

What's wrong?

**Edit - and partial answer:**

After some more google research if found on [angularfirebase.com](https://angularfirebase.com/snippets/check-if-current-user-exists-with-angularfire/) that the authState should be called as

```
const user: firebase.User = await this.fireAuth.authState.pipe(first()).toPromise();
```

However this confuses me because i used the code below before i decided to change to observables instead of plain variables. The code worked, however i see no sign of any array which is returned by `authState`

```
this.fireAuth.authState.subscribe((user: firebase.User) => {
  if (user) {
    this.getUserData(user.uid);
  }
});
```

What is happening and why is my solution working?

Comment: What happens if you do: `const user = await this.fireAuth.authState.pipe(first()).toPromise();`?

Comment: Interestingly that works as i also found out a few minutes ago. But why do i need to use `pipe(first())`? I updated the question feel free to answer that problem

Answer (score 1):

`toPromise()` creates a promise that will be resolved when the stream completes.

So if `this.fireAuth.authState` never completes, but emits values you can use the `first` operator to create a stream that completes after the first emitted value. Thus the promise resolves.

The subscribe handler on the other hand is called for every value.